# "can't connect to any url" and "authentication not supported"

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a Git repo and project on Eclipse. I am trying to share project on github. But i always get this error:

```
 Can't connect to any URI:
 https://github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git
 (https://github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git: authentication
 not supported)
```

I have tried the solutions of people who have encountered this problem but nothing has changed. In my opinion, my git password is not going and I can not write my password when I use the console. I am beginner. I want to understand why happened and how can i fix?

Comment: Goto Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> right side panel update time to 3000. `Connection timeout (seconds): 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be linked to your version of Eclipse/EGit, because of "[Discontinue support for weak cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/)".

Try again with the latest version of Eclipse/EGit, to make sure it does not use TLSv1.0 which has been disabled on GitHub side.

Comment: thank you for comment. I checked Egit is lastest version and TLSv1.0 is disabled. I test tls1.0 to ensure "TLS 1.0 Deactivation Test Passed". And I added eclipse.ini "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2." But i am getting same error.

Comment: @Nea Do you have a git credential helper set up? (git config credential.helper) Is it "manager"? Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Nea Then open your Windows Credential Manager, and look for any github entry: the credential cached there might be incorrect.

Comment: @Nea Is it a private repo?

Comment: No, it is public. And my password, username is correct.

Comment: @Nea that's strange: you don't even need authentication for cloning a public repo.

Comment: @Nea Can you share some links to process you already followed?

Comment: When i cloning repo, there is no error. But when i commit or share project on github, i am seeing the error above. My process: "Team>Share Project>Create repository" and then "Team>commit" and then "Team>Push the upstream"

Comment: @Nea If you have cloned through Eclipse, no need to "Team>Share Project>Create repository" again. If you have cloned through command-line, then only "Team>Share Project" should be enough (no need to create)

Comment: The above process is to share the new project on github. Cloned process: go Git perspective>Clone a Git repo.. . a strange situation for me. I do not understand why. I do it like I did before.

Comment: @Nea Can you try the same clone with an SSH URL?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by increasing the timeout. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem..  Goto Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> On  right side panel update time to 2500. `Connection timeout (seconds): 2500. – Hope it will help

Comment: Better to comment this kind of answers